# Scrapy Shell FormRequest

Tags: xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape some ajax content from http://lsgelection.kerala.gov.in/lbtrend2015/views/lnkResultsGrama.php

Once the two dropdowns are selected and submitted, from chrome networks tab

```
Request URL: http://lsgelection.kerala.gov.in/lbtrend2015/includes/detailed_results_grama_ajax.php
Request Method: POST
```

FormData

```
token: 9fd54c089d36035c3ce2b5cf08f38982
process: getGramaWonCandData
cno: 46
districtCode: D02001
Panchayat: G02069
```

I tried to scrape data from scrapy shell along with splash, as `cno` comes from JS

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://lsgelection.kerala.gov.in/lbtrend2015/views/lnkResultsGrama.php'

token = response.xpath('//input[@id="token"]/@value').extract_first()
cno = response.xpath('//input[@id="cno"]/@value').extract_first()
```

Then i tried to fetch the form response using

```
fetch(scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,url='http://lsgelection.kerala.gov.in/lbtrend2015/includes/detailed_results_grama_ajax.php',method='POST',formdata={'token':token,'process': 'getGramaWonCandData','cno':cno,'districtCode': 'D02001','Panchayat': 'G02069'},headers={'Content-Type': 'json/...'}))
```

When i tried to get `response.text` or `response.body` it is returning `b'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'`

Where have i gone wrong ?

Comment: If that's the actual content-type header you're sending, it's part of the problem: the actual content type is `application/json`. I am also about 90% certain you don't want to use `FormRequest` to send a json payload

Comment: Response Headers Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  and Request Headers Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Comment: I tried with `  
  `fetch(scrapy.Request(url='http://lsgelection.kerala.gov.in/lbtrend2015/includes/detailed_results_grama_ajax.php',method='POST',body=json.dumps({'token':token,'process': 'getGramaWonCandData','cno':cno,'districtCode': 'D02001','Panchayat': 'G02069'}),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8','Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})) ` but the result was same.